# After upgrading 2.0.9 to 2.1.2 Product data is not displayed in admin panel when i edit a product

Tags: magento2, upgrade, adminform, magento-2.1.2, magento-2.0.9

I have upgraded magento using `Magento web setup wizard` from **`2.0.9` to `2.1.2`** latest.

Now on front-end products are displayed properly, **but when I trying to edit any product all details displayed blank.**

It means that in backend showing no data.

Please help me to solve this issue.

In theme **magento luma** is used.

[image]